# Android detecting on touch inside fragment

Tags: android, fragment

[image]

I have two fragments in my activity.  Fragment2 overlaps Fragment1.  And Fragment1 takes up the entire screen.  When the user taps Fragment1 I would like Fragment2 to disappear.

My question is how can I determine that Fragment1 was tapped?

Fragment1 is mostly made up of a webview which I was thinking I could use its setOnTouchListener but it doesn't seem to ever be called.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Bradley4

This is how I implemented the onTouchListener:

1) first I implemented "OnTouchListener"

```
public class Frag_ItemDetail extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener {
```

2)then I overrode onTouch

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
Log.d("myclass", "onTouch"); 
return false;
}
```

3) then I set the setOnTouchListener to my webview

```
WebView itemFullDescription = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemFullDescription);
WebView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I set the onTouchListenerner on a button and it worked fine.  It just isnt' working for the webview.

Comment: i've posted some code snippets.  I'm going to try something at the activity level now and hopefully I'll have better luck.

Comment: I used onInterceptTouchEvent() instead which works well with WevViews.

Comment: registering a touch listener with Fragment has no effect I believe, you should target the root view/layout instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469651/why-my-fragments-ontouch-and-onclick-method-still-response-when-it-has-star

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I extended the `LinearLayout` class and overrode `onInterceptTouchEvent` so if `Fragment1` is touched `Fragment2` would disappear, which is working.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt your return false be return true? If activity 2 is touched(or the webview) it should be returning as true. or vice versa

Comment: Thanks for your help Yoshi24, but changing to true didn't help.