# Why my fragment's ontouch() and onClick() method still response when it has started another frament

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has a fragment A and fragment B, the fragment A contains a `GridView` and a `ListView` like below:

```
             fragment A
-------------------------------------
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|        GridView A     | ListView A |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
--------------------------------------
```

and the fragment B contains a `ListView` and a `LinearLayout` as below:

```
--------------------------------------
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
| ListView B |     LinearLayout B    |
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
|            |                       |
--------------------------------------
```

When clicking an item of `ListView` A on fragment A, it will start fragment B and shows the details information of the item. But at fragment B when I touch the screen which used to be the area of `GridView` A or `ListView` A, it still response the `GridView` A's onTouch() method or `ListView` A's `onClick()` method. This is the first time I used `Fragment`, I am confused this for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the touches are leaking through to the first fragment. I would set a onTouch Listener on the root layout of fragment B to prevent the touches from going through when its layout is visible.

So for something along these lines:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentBlayout, container, false);
    root.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
        /** Intercepts touches from going through. */
        return true;
        }
    });

    /** Find the rest of your views... */

   return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering me. And its a good work around for my problem. But why a view in a fragment will response the callback method registered at another fragment?

Comment: I think it is because your laying views on top of each other. I can't think of a good reason why you would want this to happen but I suppose if a developer needed the back view to somehow react to the touch as well then it would have that option.