# How to set onClick listener for a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

I am working with Android Studio. I have a fragment on my Activty and I want to hide it when the user clicks on it.

For some reason I can´t just override a function for onclick like in the activties. And everytime I ask google all I can find are questions about how to
Implement onclick listeners for buttons or other elements in a fragment but that is not what I want. I want the onclick listener for the fragment itself.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that!?

Comment: where's is your code??

Comment: Try to set  a onclick listeners to the root view of the fragment.

Comment: @kirankumar I don´t have any buttons to hide

Comment: [This thread looks to be the answer to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113707/android-detecting-on-touch-inside-fragment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by set `ClickListener` on the view inflating in a `onCreateView` of fragment like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_your, container, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your operation here
            // this will be called whenever user click anywhere in Fragment
        }
    });
 return v;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It goes like below

```
public class fragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button myButton;

    @Override
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        myButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // implements your things
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! but why do you add the onClickListener to the button. I don´t have any buttons in my fragment

Comment: replace it with whatever view you want to use...that was to show you how its done!!