# Buttons are not clicking when using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using one fragment on one page. In the fragment page I have a form which has two TextView which act like dropdown buttons then I have two editTextviews and also an Image on the toolbar which should be clickable to go on to the next page, but these buttons are not working. I'm not sure why this is happening Can someone help me solve this issue maybe you'll see something that I dont. My code is below, thanks in advance

```
//Fragment1.java

public class Fragment_form1 extends Fragment {


    View view;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_all_in_one, container, false);
        //view.setClickable(true);
        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setFocusable(true);


        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return view;
    }
}

  //Main page 

   next_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment_form1 fragment_form1=new Fragment_form1();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager2=getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout2,fragment_form1).setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right_to_left, R.anim.exit_right_to_left,R.anim.enter_left_to_right, R.anim.exit_left_to_right).commit();
            }
        });

//activity.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    tools:context="com.myapp.loook.AllInOneActivity">




    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/metoolbar1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/next_again"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:clickable="false"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>














    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/metoolbar1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

        >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            >



            <!--
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:text="What are you advertising?"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />
-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choose"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textColorLink="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Choose a category"


                />

            <!--
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="URL Link"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />
                -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birth"
                android:hint="Birth day"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"


                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textColorLink="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />
            <!--

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="Call-To-Action"
                                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal"
                                />
                                -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/color"
                android:hint="Favorite Color"


                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textColorLink="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="25/25"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/silver"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="25"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:hint="Bio"
                android:padding="27dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textColorLink="@color/secondary_text"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"

                >
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Image"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                    android:id="@+id/upload_button"
                    android:padding="37dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Photo must be at least 940 x 788px
(recommended)"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:text="change photo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:paddingStart="25dp"



                />








        </LinearLayout>












    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If all of those `View`s you describe are in the `Fragment`'s layout, you need to set them up in the `Fragment`, not in the `Activity`. Also, you need to remove the `setClickable()` and `setFocusable()` calls you have there now; otherwise, they may cause problems with the inner `View`s receiving touch events properly.

Comment: How should i do that @MikeM.

Comment: You can do something like is shown in the examples on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630063). Those are just setting an `OnClickListener` on a `Button`, but the main point is how to find the inner `View`s. After that, if you need to do any other setup – e.g., setting text, changing colors, etc. – you would do it basically the same way you would in an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set Clickable and Focusable on the TextView rather than the inflated View.

So after you inflate your view. You should find the textview by:

`view.findViewById(R.id. next_arrow).setOnClickListener(...)`

Comment: I tried it but its I get a warning error when I try to put this inside setOnClickListener         view.findViewById(R.id.click).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent inty=new Intent(Fragment_form1.this,"Clicked",PreviewActivity.class);
                startActivity(inty);
            }
        });